# No image display window in cv_bridge tutorial. (Does compressed image matter?

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the cv_bridge [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages)

The code is correct(I just copy the code and change the topic name to mine `/camera/image` ), also modified the CMakeLists.xml.

The catkin_build is successful without error.

But when I run the node, there is nothing showed up.

The node should run up successfully because new topics show up.

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image
/camera/image/compressed
/image_converter/output_video
/image_converter/output_video/compressed
/image_converter/output_video/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_converter/output_video/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_converter/output_video/compressedDepth
/image_converter/output_video/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image_converter/output_video/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image_converter/output_video/theora
/image_converter/output_video/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image_converter/output_video/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Also I can view the image using `image_view`

`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image _image_transport:=compressed`

I'm afraid maybe the compressed video matters so I change add the command when running:

```
$ rosparam set /compressed_listener/image_transport compressed
$ rosrun mypackage mynode __name:=compressed_listener
```

http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/ExaminingImagePublisherSubscriber

But still no display window...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171726/no-image-display-window-in-cv_bridge-tutorial.-(does-compressed-image-matter?/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-30**:
Are any images published on the /image_converter/output_video topic? You should be able to verify that images are being published with

```
rostopic hz
```

or

```
rostopic echo
```

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-30**:
@ahendrix nothing... I ran `rostopic echo /image_converter/output_video` but got nothing. I think the subscribe of video topic failed.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-30**:
I guess maybe the image_transport matters because when I subscribe I just use the code `image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/camera/image", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);` while for image_view, I need to set `_image_transport=compressed` to see the video. But I don't know what to change here...

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-31**:
@ahendrix Thanks so much! it works, but could you teach me how to find the parameter need to remap?  first I searched the source and wiki of image_transport and cv_bridge with key work`compressed`, but I got nothing... I really want to know how to get the answer when I face that kind of problem

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-02**:
to be honest, I'm not sure what the appropriate parameter to change here is. I suspect it's namespaced to the topic name, but I'd have to read the source for image_transport to really understand it.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-06-03**:
@ahendrix Thanks again, I read the document again and now I can understand it much better. Also, could you convert it into the answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try constructing your listener with the extra argument specifying the transport hint:

```
image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/camera/image", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this, image_transport::TransportHints("compressed"));
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2